# Use dll-function in python with ctypes | python 2.7 vs. 3.6

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a C++-Library (example.dll) with some functions and want to use them from Python. I got it working with `ctypes` and Python 2.7, but not with Python 3.6.

Here an excerpt from example.h :

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LONG _stdcall func1(LPTSTR filename, long cbAddress);
```

The function is parsing a txt-file, loads some data to the memory and returns a handle to this data.

My code for Python 2.7 is:

```
from ctypes import *

mydll = WinDLL(r'C:\temp\example.dll')
txt_path = c_char_p(r'C:\temp\file.txt')

func1 = mydll['func1']
func1.restype = c_long
func1.argtypes = (c_char_p , c_void_p)
handle = func1(txt_path, None)
```

This is working and returns a valid handle.

With Python 3.6, line 3 causes an error:

```
>>> txt_path = c_char_p(r'C:\temp\file.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

so I changed it to

```
txt_path = c_char_p(b'C:\temp\file.txt')
```

which is working, but leads to a problem with the function. `func1` returns now 0, which is an intern error code for "could not read txt-file."

I tried to use different types, but it didn't work and I'm kind of stuck now.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to escape the backslashes, i.e. use `\\` instead of `\` (or possibly use forward slashes). You can have a look at what's returned by `print(b'C:\temp\file.txt')`

Comment: So simple and I didn't see it, but that was the solution! Thanks!

Comment: Pretty cool! Could you accept the answer below (assuming it's satisfying) so that it may help others having the same type of issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply the escaping of backslashes (someone with a cynical point of view might say the issue is Windows) the line in question `txt_path = c_char_p(b'C:\temp\file.txt')` had to be changed to:

```
txt_path = c_char_p(b'C:\\temp\\file.txt')
```